# Cannot pass a simplified function to onClick event handler ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have two Components, Main and Menu Component. Main Component is the parent component of Menu. Menu shows a list of items and upon clicking one of the item, it updates Main's state with the help of a function that I pass as props to Menu. Below is the code for better understanding:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishes: dishes,
            selectedDish: null
        };
        this.selectDish=this.selectDish.bind(this);
      }

      selectDish(dishId){
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
      }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={this.selectDish} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

And below is the Menu Component:

```
class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.selectdish=this.selectdish.bind(this);
    }
    selectdish(dishId){
        return this.props.onClick(dishId);
    }

    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card key={dish.id}
                  onClick={this.selectdish(dish.id)}>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
        });

    }
}

export default Menu;
```

I have omissed some irrelevant parts of the code.
So the workflow should be that when we click over one of dishes rendered by the Menu, that dish's id should be passed back to Main and update the state variable ```selectedDish````, as seen in the method `selectDish`.

But in the browser console, I get the error `Cannot update during existing state transition`.
The weird thing is that if I don't pass any dish id and set the `selectedDish` to a fixed value like 1, everything works fine.

Please help me guys to identify if there is any problem in my event handler, because that is the only part that seems to contain an error.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `onClick` of the Card a function but you are already calling that function with `this.selectdish(dish.id)`. This will initiate the flow on render, not on click.

You have three options here.

You either wrap that in an additional function like this: `onClick={() => {this.selectdish(dish.id)}}>`. That way, you are passing a function to the onClick, which is required, and not executing that.

Or you make `selectdish` return a function like this:

```
 selectdish(dishId){
    return () => {this.props.onClick(dishId)};
}
```

Or you add a name to the card and access the name of the element from the click event:

```
class Menu extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.selectdish=this.selectdish.bind(this);
}
selectdish(event){
    return this.props.onClick(event.target.name);
}

render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
        return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <Card key={dish.id}
              name={dish.id}
              onClick={this.selectdish}> // this is now the function without calling it
            </Card>
          </div>
        );
    });

}
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why you said that function will be executed during render. In plain javascript, we do it like that itself.

Comment: this.selectdish(dish.id) will execute a function right? So  onClick={this.selectdish(dish.id)}> will also execute the function on render

Comment: why on render, it should be executed on click. I can't get that part.

Comment: One more thing, why we're even returning the function inside selectdish. Why can't we just caall the function?

Comment: Because whenever you write function(), you execute it. And you are doing that. YOu need to wrap that in an additional function and pass that function to the onClick to be executed on Click,

Comment: Because onClick needs a function to be called on Click, but you are calling the function, when you call onCLick={function()}. It just needs to be onClick={function}

Comment: So you mean if we remove the paranthesis then the function will be called on click, not on the render. Right? So it is different from plain javascript

Comment: Yes, onClick will execute anything passed in the onClick on click, it needs to be a plain function instead. And no thats how javascript works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215414/discussion-between-domino987-and-vipul-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your code:

1. property `key` must be define in root `<div>`
2. render method in Menu component returns nothing

-

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectdish = this.selectdish.bind(this);
  }
  selectdish(dishId) {
    return this.props.onClick(dishId);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.dishes.map(dish => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1" key={dish.id}>
          <div onClick={() => this.selectdish(dish.id)}>{dish.id}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

See my playground where I fixed this issues:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-ib6pr?file=/index.js

Comment: I have removed that part.